# In CLion, How do I get auto-format multiline function calls for single indentation?

Tags: c++, indentation, clion, function-call, autoformatting

I want my function calls to look like so:

```
my_function(arg1, arg2_1 + something_long_here + something_else + a_third_thing
    + a_fourth_thing, arg3);
```

i.e. for the second line onwards to be indented an extra level (either a tab, or the equivalent number of spaces if I use spaces).

However, in CLion, the auto-formatting gives me this:

```
my_function(arg1, arg2_1 + something_long_here + something_else + a_third_thing
                  + a_fourth_thing, arg3);
```

i.e. spaces up until the same column as the beginning of the specification of the same argument on the previous line.

How can I get CLion to format my code the way I want to?

Comment: Clion should detect and use clang-format if you add one to the project directory. Aside from that if you double tab shift key and type in format you should be able to navigate to the format settings

Comment: @Taekahn: 1. I'm not sure what you mean by "double tab shift". 2. Ok, so, how do I achieve this with clang-format?

Comment: That was an autocorrect. I meant to say double tap shift. I.e `shift + shift`. As for clang-format there is a nice online tool https://zed0.co.uk/clang-format-configurator/